# Problem with HtmlPanelGrid.setRowClasses()

Tags: css, jsf

I have one more question! I am trying to configure HtmlPanelGrid from bean. I bound panelGrid to this bean and want to set css row classes.
Here is me stylesheet.css:

```
.list-row-even { 
background-color: silver;
}

.list-row-odd { 
 background-color: red;
}
```

my jsf page:

```
   <rich:tab label="Top-List" id="screenTop">
     <h:panelGrid id="topListTable" binding="#{chartBean.topListTable}" />
   </rich:tab>
```

and my bean:

```
public TopListChartWrapper(Iterator<Entry> treeIt) {
    this.grid = new HtmlPanelGrid();
    //this.grid.setBgcolor("yellow");
    this.grid.setColumns(2);
    this.grid.setBorder(0);
    this.grid.setCellpadding("0");
    this.grid.setCellspacing("0");
    this.grid.setWidth("100%");
    this.grid.setRowClasses("list-row-even, list-row-odd");   
    this.treeIterator = treeIt;
    this.prepareGrid();
}
```

Any ideas? maybe somewhere I need register my stylesheet?

Thanks!

Comment: You forgot to tell about the **problem**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry - about forget the question)
I figure out what was wrong:
I need replace the line:

     `link href="./css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"`

with this one:

```
 link href="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/css/default.css" rel="styleSheet" type="text/css"/
```

Thanks!

Comment: Ah, the stylesheets weren't loaded. In the future please be more clear about the problem.

Comment: I am newborn here? how can I set this question as answered?